# How to do a bare minimum install of Xcode such that I can compile common UNIX applications

Tags: mac, xcode, gcc

I just got a new macbook air where every bit of SSD disk space is precious. I want to be able to compile & run most of the open source tools out there. I figured out I needed to install Xcode but it has consumed 6.3G of my disk space. I am sure I don't need 99% of all those stuff.

Now how do I reclaim my space without sacrificing the ability to compile UNIX programs. I am assuming here that the most common applications are available in C/C++ source codes and hence I primarily require a gcc more than anything else. Please correct me if other libraries are also required. I read at other places that I can customize the install but I was unable to do so. I tried downloading dmg file as well as downloading via Appstore. In either case, mac took care of all the installation without bothering me to interfere and customize. I am a mac newbie, sure I must have missed something.

Even otherwise, how can i shed the unnecessary software bloat without having to reinstall.

Comment: OK I reran Monlingual which reclaimed around 93M space. Staggering amount of space is allotted to "Platforms" subdirectory (4.5G) followed by "documentation". I am blindly convinced both of them are unnecessary but will wait until someone gives me an informed advice. The uninstall perl script shows 4 modes `all;xcodedir;unixdev;system support`. I think I should retain unixdev and run other two modes. Can someone advise?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can uncheck the 'ios sdk' and leave the others checked during install to only install basic tools and c++, but I've never done this. The ios sdk is like 3.8GB of the xcode install.

Comment: I tried installing twice, but both the times I was not given any option to check or uncheck anything. Perhaps I clicked through some screen. Anyways, I ran the uninstall perl script with mode=xcodedir and recovered some 6 GB space. Still the Xcode has eaten up some amount of disk space and I am not sure where. I guess, I should stop being paranoid and get on with it.

Comment: Does the Xcode IDE and c/c++ suff still work? Curious, I might do that too if it does. I have zero desire to develop IOS apps...

Comment: I just checked `gcc-v`. Let me know the test cases I need to check, otherwise I cannot confirm which functionalities were lost.

Comment: Can you still use the Xcode 4 IDE (the blueprint & hammer app) or was that deleted?

Comment: No Xcode and other stuffs were gone, including the Developer directory. So I would suggest not to go this way. I even tried to open the installer package and manually install components one by one. Still some libraries were missing for me to compile some stuff. I wasn't sure which were the pre-requisites, so in the end I resorted back to full install.